# Passing variables to awk script with just a couple of awk commands

Tags: variables, awk

I am very new to awk so apologies for this question.

I have made a script with lots of awk commands (called it "myscript.awk", e.g:

```
awk -v f=5 -v t=62 '{ for (i=f; i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s", $i,(i==t) ? "\n" : OFS = "\t") }' myfiles > testa3.maf
awk -v f=1 -v t=4 '{ for (i=f; i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s", $i,(i==t) ? "\n" : OFS = "\t") }' myfiles > testa4.maf
paste testa3.maf testa4.maf > myfiles.txt
```

This is just an example, but the real script has a lot of other awk commands as well. I now want to pass this to thousands of files, so it applies these commands to all the files.

I've tried assigning my file to a variable (as I have shown in the script as myfile) and ran as such:

```
awk -v myfiles="test.maf" -f myscript.awk
```

But I am getting a syntax error. I must be doing something very wrong!

Thanks

Comment: What are the input files?  `myfiles` always, or does it vary?  How do you derive the name `testa3.maf` and `testa4.maf` from the arguments?  Do you keep the intermediate `.maf` files around after you created `myfiles.txt`?  Most of this should probably done in the shell script launching the Awk scripts, but since you've not provided information about the input and output (and intermediate) files, it is hard to help you.

Comment: Hi sorry. The input will be a list of files, which should be assigned to myfiles. testa3.maf and testa4.maf are just intermediate files which can be overwritten with each iteration, but won't matter because there will be a separate output file for each input file at the end of each iteration anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish a shell script from an awk script. In your case,

```
awk -v f=1 -v t=4 '{ for (i=f; i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s", $i,(i==t) ? "\n" : OFS = "\t") }' testa.maf > testa4.maf
```

is a shell command. The three commands you posted are a shell script. This is an awk script that the above shell script is executing:

```
{ for (i=f; i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s", $i,(i==t) ? "\n" : OFS = "\t") }
```

If you named that script `script.awk`. you could execute it using `awk -v f=1 -v t=4 -f script.awk`. Shell scripts are not executed by `awk`, but (typically) by `sh` or `bash`.

Shell scripts can also have variables, but they function differently than awk variables. Specifically, if you want that shell script to have a variable for the output file, you could do this:

```
file="$1"
awk -v f=5 -v t=62 '{ for (i=f; i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s", $i,(i==t) ? "\n" : OFS = "\t") }' $file > testa3.maf
awk -v f=1 -v t=4 '{ for (i=f; i<=t;i++) printf("%s%s", $i,(i==t) ? "\n" : OFS = "\t") }' testa.maf > testa4.maf
paste testa3.maf testa4.maf > $file.txt
```

Here, `$1` is the first passed parameter; then you can call your script:

```
bash script.sh test.maf
```